# delete eclipse project using ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

do somebody know how to delete eclipse project using ant?

I'm using eclipse in silent mode, to run ant build scripts and before build I'd like to delete 2 project which are generated automatically by eclipse. Is there any option? (Something like `<eclipse.deleteProject />`)

thanks in advance

Comment: how about ant delete dir?

Comment: delete the .project file, and the project is alien for eclipse from then!!

Comment: Also make sure Eclipse is not running -- it may lock resources so you may be not able to delete them.

Comment: No, if I delete only .project and that dir, eclipse still hold information about that project somewhere in .metadata folder. So I need some task to delete this regullary with eclipse api.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing eclipse exposes by default to ant, AFAICT.  I'd use ant to delete the folder (as suggested) and then use the `eclipse.refreshLocal` task on the workspace root.  For what eclipse does expose, see [Ant tasks provided by the platform](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_eclipse_tasks.htm&cp=2_0_18_1).